# Button expand animation appears below other elements

Tags: android, android-animation

So I have a custom keyboard and i have expand animation for each of the buttons on it but when a button is pressed some of the button expand animation is happening below the other buttons:[image]

This is how my button looks.

```
        <Button
            android:text="т"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_keyboard"
            android:textColor="@color/keyboard_text_color"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/keyboard_button_height"
            android:onClick="@{(v)-> onClickListener.onKeyboardInput(v)}"
            android:stateListAnimator="@animator/button_large_expand_animation"
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button4" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button12"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button13"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button13" android:textAlignment="center"/>
```

And this is the animation:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:state_pressed="true">
    <set>
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="100"
            android:propertyName="scaleX"
            android:valueTo="1.5"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="100"
            android:propertyName="scaleY"
            android:valueTo="1.5"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </set>
</item>
<!-- base state -->
<item android:state_enabled="true">
    <set>
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="200"
            android:propertyName="scaleX"
            android:startDelay="100"
            android:valueTo="1"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="200"
            android:propertyName="scaleY"
            android:startDelay="100"
            android:valueTo="1"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </set>
</item>
<item>
    <set>
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="0"
            android:propertyName="scaleX"
            android:valueTo="1"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="0"
            android:propertyName="scaleY"
            android:valueTo="1"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </set>
</item>
```

What I tried:

```
    button.rootView.bringToFront()
    button.rootView.requestFocusFromTouch()
```

I have no idea how to fix this any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT** 
Ok a little update i replaced 
`button.rootView.bringToFront()` with `button.bringToFront()` and it works BUT the bring to front happens after the animation hapends. So the first time you click the button the animation is below the other elements but when you press it again it is above the elements since i am using 
`android:stateListAnimator="@animator/button_large_expand_animation"` do you guys have an idea how to do this without adding a animation listener to all of the buttons and doing the bringToFront() in onAnimationStart().

Comment: Can you post the XML of the layout of the activity/fragment?

Comment: When you expand the button add elevation as well and when the button goes back to inactive remove the added elevation for ex: inactive buttons have elevation 4 dp and selected has elevation 5 dp this should draw the higher elevation on top of the lower elevation. If you use some custom viewGroup then you need to handle this yourself by drawing the selected view last so it is drawn on top.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `elevation` `objectAnimator` to your `stateListAnimator`:

(example values for the elevated state; you might need to tweak the `valueTo` value)

```
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="200"
    android:propertyName="elevation"
    android:valueTo="6dp"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
```